# Quadro K600/PCIe/SSE2 graphics card support for tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I run the following to check if GPU is supported.

```
tf.Session(config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement = True))
```

I get the following:

```
2019-04-20 16:19:28.087949: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
2019-04-20 16:19:28.147075: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1105] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Quadro K600 major: 3 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8755
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 973.31MiB freeMemory: 163.19MiB
2019-04-20 16:19:28.147137: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1168] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: Quadro K600, pci bus id: 0000:04:00.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.
Device mapping: no known devices.
2019-04-20 16:19:28.149702: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:297] Device mapping:
```

Does this mean there is no easy way to utilize the "Quadro K600/PCIe/SSE2" graphics card? In this case, is there still a need to install tensorflow-gpu than the cpu version?

Comment: The results show that GPU operations are supported in your environment. But your memory is too small. There's only `163.19MiB` left over from `973.31MiB`.  I recommend you change to a better GPU, otherwise your program will not have any computing advantage even if it runs.

Comment: It's not just the memory that is too small. The error message clearly states that the GPU in the system has compute capability 3.0, but that compute capability 3.5 is the minimum required.